# ¿Como eliminar una fila de un DataFrame de Python según la condición?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

tengo un inconveniente, necesito eliminar las filas que contengan solo string de un DataFrame de Python. es decir, por ejemplo tengo el siguiente DataFrame.

| Una cabecera | Otra cabecera |
| --- | --- |
| 25 | M-25 |
| 20 | M-20 |
| 30 | SOLO CARACTERES |
| 40 | PARA BORRAR |
| 50 | 70 |

Quiero hacer una depuración y que las filas en la columna Relacion que no contengan números sean eliminadas, he tratado con la herramienta de pandas

```py
df = df.drop('Relacion',type(Relación) == str)
```

Pero esto me elimina toda la columna y requiero solo las filas unicamente con caracteres, es decir, las combinaciones str+int son validas.
Gracias.

Comment: si pudieras colocar tu DataFrame como texto sería excelente

Comment: listo amigo, como tal ingrese el DataFrame

Answer (score 1):

Replicando tu DataFrame de esta forma:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
                    [25, "M-15"], 
                    [20, "SOLO CARACTERES"],
                    [30, "PARA BORRAR"],
                    [50, "M-25"],
                    [60, "M-60"]]),
                   columns=['Numeros', 'Relacion'])
```

Y utilizando la siguiente instrucción:

```
df[df['Relacion'].str.contains('\d+')]
```

Filtro los campos sin dígitos.

```
Numeros Relacion
0   25  M-15
3   50  M-25
4   60  M-60
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, me funciono.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta que te dieron mas que eliminar solo hace un filtro, que igualmente es válido. Si quieres eliminar verdaderamente los datos utiliza el método `drop()`, que como primer parámetro recibe una condición.

```py
df.drop(df[~df["Relacion"].str.contains('\d+')].index, inplace=True) #no hagas una asignación
print(df)
```

donde decimos que si contiene un número sea eliminado, pero como no queremos eso negamos la expresión con `~`, lo que indicaría que borre todo lo que **no contenga** un número, con esto los datos ya serán eliminados.

Comment: Genial amigo, muchas gracias